# Limit of a n-th root

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I need to show the limit of the sequence $ (a_n)= \sqrt[n]{n^3 +2} $

I thought about:

$ (a_n) = (n^3+2)^{1/n} = e^{ln(n^3+2)^{1/n}} = e^{\frac{ln(n^3+2)}{n}}$

So the limit of $ \frac{ln(n^3+2)}{n} $ (with n -> inf.) seems to be 0, but how can I prove THIS?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use the l'Hospiltal theorem.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am not allowed to use l'Hospital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squeezing hint:

$$\sqrt[n]2\le\sqrt[n]{n^3+2}\le\sqrt[n]{2}\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)^3$$